# Match any string from list to a single hash

Tags: hash, jwt

This might be a noob question, I've searched the web but couldn't find anything remotely close to what I would like to achieve. Maybe I don't have the correct jargon, so please bear with me.

Basically, I am building an application based on microservices with a single authorization server that distributes JWT's, which are being verified by the various apps. The problem is, each user will have access to different parts (and parts of parts) of the whole system and storing all the permissions in a JWT seems like a waste, let alone a security issue, but I would also like to avoid hitting the database on each call to any app.

Say, a user has an access to a list of `playgrounds` which there can be tens or more of, distributed across multiple apps in the ecosystem (please don't question the architecture, it is very specific). Also, the their permissions might be different in each `playground`. I would need to verify this against the JWT if they tried to access any of them.

I was thinking - besides hashing each `playground`'s and permission (to add a bit of security at least) and appending it to a list in the JWT, inevitably making it huge - **is there a way I could take a list of id's (think uuids) and turn them into a single hash that could be *matched against any single of them?***

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me, could you indicate what the hash is used for in the first place? I gather it is not part of the JWT specifications?

Comment: Say a user wants to access `playground 42`, the target app checks if `playground 42` is included (for a lack of a better term) in the hash that combines all the `playgronds` that the user can access (stored in the jwt as to not call the auth server and hit the DB every time). The use of the hash is to hide what the user has access to, but mainly to avoid having to store a long list of permissions in the jwt.

Comment: If there is another way I could verify the permissions per user per playground without calling the auth server, then I'm all ears. (btw storing the permissions in each and every app's database is not viable)